# Why does Firefox not auto-detect the proxy after upgrading to version 31?

Tags: networking, firefox, proxy, network-adapter, socks-proxy

My Firefox cannot detect the proxy any more after upgrading it to version 31. The proxy setting inside Firefox network option is *Auto-detect proxy settings for this network*. Before upgrading to version 30 Firefox could detect the proxy without restarting Firefox, but now it cannot detect even with restarting.

Google Chrome can detect it very well.

What can I do to make Firefox discover the proxy again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to enable NTLMv1 authentication in the `about:config`. Follow the instructions in the security section from the [Firefox release notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/30/Site_Compatibility#Security).

Answer (score 0):

My Problem Solved by downgrading to version 30 again!!

Comment: That’s not exactly a solution, now is it? If you think Firefox is misbehaving, you may well have found a bug. So go report it. :)